# continuous adding of value from two labels

Tags: vb.net

```
Public Shared total1 As Integer = 0
Public Shared total2 As Integer = 0



Private Sub BtnAdult_Click(ByVal sendenr As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnAdult.Click
    Dim addADult As Integer = 50

    total1 = Val(total1) + Val(addADult)
    total2 = Val(total2) + Val(addADult)

    If RadioButton1.Checked Then
        Sales.lblErick.Text = Val(total1)
        Sales.Show()
        Me.Hide()

    ElseIf RadioButton2.Checked Then
        Sales.lblHenry.Text = Val(total2)
        Sales.Show()
        Me.Hide()

    End If
End Sub

Private Sub BtnChild_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnChild.Click
    Static hits As Integer = 0
    hits += 1

    Dim addChild As Integer = 45
    total1 = Val(total1) + Val(addChild)
    total2 = Val(total2) + Val(addChild)

    If RadioButton1.Checked Then
        Sales.lblErick.Text = Val(total1)
        Sales.Show()
        Me.Hide()

    ElseIf RadioButton2.Checked Then
        Sales.lblHenry.Text = Val(total2)
        Sales.Show()
        Me.Hide()
'...
```

ok i have two radio buttons
then i have two label
when i checked 1 radiobutton, then tick the btnAdult
i want my label to have a value of 0+ 50
and when i went back again to check the other button
it just adds to the value of the other label ..
supposedly 
if checked the other radiobutton and tick btnAdult
my other label.text  becomes 100,
it supposed  to start with 50
what should i do...

Comment: If your variables are Integers then you don't need that horrible `Val` function when doing math.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you call this code on every click

```
total1 = Val(total1) + Val(addADult)
total2 = Val(total2) + Val(addADult)
```

Means, every time you press the button totals will go +50

If you want a fix, then make it like this:

```
    Dim addADult As Integer = 50




    If RadioButton1.Checked Then
        total1 = Val(total1) + Val(addADult)
        Sales.lblErick.Text = Val(total1)
        Sales.Show()
        Me.Hide()

    ElseIf RadioButton2.Checked Then
        total2 = Val(total2) + Val(addADult)
        Sales.lblHenry.Text = Val(total2)
        Sales.Show()
        Me.Hide()

    End If
End Sub
```

Or place the total's math inside the radiobutton's brackets

Comment: Nothing just happened sir.. My label.text doesnt add it just become 50 everytime i click the btnAdult

Comment: That was general answer, I don't know what you're trying to do. I GUESS that you want to keep results, so the last edit should work. Next time be more specific, if you want to get specific answer.

Comment: can i have your email sir??

Comment: i have 2 radiobutton..
2 button 
and two labels

when i checked  radiobutton1  and click the btnAdult my label1 should be 50

i clicked btnAdult again -radiobutton1checked my label1 output should be 100...

i checked radiobutton2 and clicked btnAdult.. my label2 output should be 50
i checked radiobutton2 and clicked btnChild.. my label2 output should be 95..

ohh please help me..
you can edit my code though or give me some new ones sorry for the inconvenience sir